# Id repetido al guardar elementos en la base de datos en app movil (android studio-java)

Tags: java, android, app, studio

estoy desarrollando una app movil en java y usando android studio.

en esa app guardo elementos y al momento de agregar dos elementos (uno con diferente id) la base de datos me guarda ambos ID. quiero saber la forma para que esto no suceda, adjunto el codigo y la imagen de las tablas donde me guarda os registros equivocados.
(como quiero que aparezcan seria, 1277 y 1291 consecutivamente pero se repite ambos id).

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            //Si la transacción es exitosa
            if (!response.equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                for(ListModel item:Items){

                    String idResiduo = mapeoResiduos.get(item.getNombreResiduo())[0].split(",")[0]; //AQUI ESTA EL ERRROR DEL ID RESIDUO

                    //Toast.makeText(context, i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); ALERTAS NOTIFICACION.
                   // Toast.makeText(context, idResiduo, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    setResiduos(context,
                            response,
                            idResiduo,
                            item.getUnidadResiduo(),
                            item.getCantidadResiduo()
                    );
                }
```

[image: en la tercer columna se repiten los id]

Comment: Seguramente estas llamando en más de una ocasión la inserción de cada elemento, es importante agregues o revises cuantas veces realizas la inserción.

Comment: Pero los demas elementos se guardan bien el unico que se guarda igual es la tercer columna (idResiduo) en el código siento que el error esta en el mapeo de los elementos pero no estoy seguro...